# SQL Query Join two tables with 1-Many relation with first table row and following rows for second table values

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I need help with a query/ PL/SQL procedure for below requirement.

Table 1:

```
T1ID      T1Name       T1Col2
 1        Name1          X
 2        Name2          Y
```

Table2 :

```
T2T1ID    T2SubName    T2Column2
1         Test1Sub1       P
1         Test1Sub2       P
1         Test1Sub3       P
2         Test2Sub1       Q
2         Test2Sub2       Q
```

I want to build a query which will fetch me

```
T1ID              T1Name              T1Col2        T2SubName      T2Column2
  1                Test1               X
                                                     Test1Sub1       P
                                                     Test1Sub2       P
                                                     Test1Sub3       P
  2                Test2               Y
                                                     Test2Sub1       Q
                                                     Test2Sub1       Q
```

Answer (score 1):

Such a "break" layout is easily achieved by any reporting tool. In SQL*Plus, `BREAK` (who'd guess?) does the job. See if it helps.

```
SQL> break on t1id on t1name on t1col2
SQL>
SQL> with
  2  t1 (t1id, t1name, t1col2) as
  3    (select 1, 'name1', 'x' from dual union
  4     select 2, 'name2', 'y' from dual
  5    ),
  6  t2 (t2t1id, t2subname, t2column2) as
  7    (select 1, 'test1sub1', 'p' from dual union
  8     select 1, 'test1sub2', 'p' from dual union
  9     select 1, 'test1sub3', 'p' from dual union
 10     select 2, 'test2sub1', 'q' from dual union
 11     select 2, 'test2sub2', 'q' from dual
 12    )
 13  select a.t1id, a.t1name, a.t1col2, b.t2subname, b.t2column2
 14  from t1 a join t2 b on b.t2t1id = a.t1id
 15  order by a.t1id;

      T1ID T1NAM T T2SUBNAME T
---------- ----- - --------- -
         1 name1 x test1sub1 p
                   test1sub2 p
                   test1sub3 p
         2 name2 y test2sub1 q
                   test2sub2 q

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use FULL OUTER JOIN with proper ORDER BY statement :

```
select t1.t1id, nvl2(t1.t1name,'Test'||t1.t1id,'') t1name, t1.col2, 
       t2.t2subname, t2.t2column2 
  from table1 t1
  full outer join table2 t2
  on ( t1.col2 = t2.t2column2 )
order by nvl(t1id,2)||nvl(t2t1id,2), nvl(t2.t2subname,'0');

T1ID    T1NAME  COL2    T2SUBNAME   T2COLUMN2
----    ------  ----    ---------   ---------
 1      Test1   X       
                        Test1Sub1   P
                        Test1Sub2   P
                        Test1Sub3   P
 2      Test2   Y       
                        Test2Sub1   Q
                        Test2Sub2   Q
```

[**db <> fiddle**  demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e702158cb02ff2e15d5a428c579fea4c)

Comment: Thanks much Barbaros, this is a great help